# Running pearson correlation test on multiple groups in a data frame

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the pearson correlation for multiple groups of a data frame by year in R. There is a column in the data frame with Years 1962-2007 in it and I would like to run the p.c. between CO2 emissions and GDP (two other columns in the data frame) for each year. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Try `?cor`, e.g. `cor(iris[, -5])`. It also lets you decide what to do when there are missings (the `use` argument).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I think can get you started:

```
str(dataset) # use this to verify that you are only getting numeric or integer values

dataset <- dataset %>%
select(x, y, z) # where x, y, z are the names for columns that are integers or numbers

options(digits=2)
correlation_table <- corrr::correlate(dataset, 
                                      method = "pearson")
correlation_table
```

All this will get you something called a correlation matrix.

This is really just a partial answer. You should read SO documentation on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide sample data when you post a question so the answer can be designed to your specific needs. Assuming you have a data frame called `df` and variables called `Year`, `CO2`, and `GDP`:

```
df.split <- split(df[, c("CO2", "GDP")], df$Year)
df.corrs <- lapply(df.split, cor)
```

will return a list called df.corrs with correlation matrices for each year. To get the correlation for the first year only, use `df.corrs[[1]]` or `df.corrs[["1962"]]`.